# Interpret TWIG's {% js %} as <script> in PHPStorm

Tags: templating, javascript, js

Does anyone know how to get PHPStorm interpret `{% js %}` as `<script>` for correct syntax highlighting in PHPStorm?

Background: I'am always doing this:

```
{% js at endBody %}
    {% if false %}<script>{% endif %}
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('overlay');
    {% if false %}</script>{% endif %}
{% endjs %}
```

which I would like to avoid.

Comment: No solution yet. Here's the [topic](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000038510-Formatting-code-within-a-Twig-Language-Injection) > [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-40602?_ga=2.61462703.287967644.1618763921-1916018252.1617364360) on Jetbrains site

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using PhpStorm’s [Language Injections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/language-injections-settings.html) feature.

In fact, as of PhpStorm 2017.3, it has included [support for `{% script %}` tag](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/12/twig-handling-improvements/)s out of the box.

To extend that to `{% js %}` tags, go to **Preferences** → **Editor** → **Language Injections**, and search for “twig: custom statement javascript”. Double-click on it to edit it, and add the following line to the **Places Patterns** setting:

```
+ twigCustomStatement("js")
```

[image: The “twig: custom statement javascript” language injection settings]

Click **OK** and then **Apply** to save.

You can also add support for interpreting `{% css %}` tag contents as CSS by duplicating that language injection, setting its Language ID to **CSS**, and setting its **Places Pattern** to:

```
+ twigCustomStatement("css")
```

[image: The settings for a new CSS language injection]

Comment: Very nice. Any idea, if it is possible to make this valid with your solution:

var host = '{{ craft.request.hostInfo }}';

Without script tags inside PHPStorm will complain.

Comment: @MatthiasRedl-Mann I’m not sure if that’s possible, sorry.

Comment: It works fine, but every css class inside csstwig tag is colored gray, like normally does if in this file there is no html element that uses that class.